# On piano, what is the fundamental reason why some arpeggios are more difficult than others?

Tags: piano

When doing exercises on piano, what is the fundamental reason why some arpeggios are more difficult than others?

Here is an example of extremely hard arpeggio (if using the fingering 1, 2, 4): A major, first inversion
[image]

I could not go faster than 95 for a quarter.

Here is an example of a difficult but much more easy : F sharp

[image]

I could play this one at 160 for a quarter with difficulty, when I'm in a very good shape.

Comment: There are too many variable to answer this question as asked -- in full generality. Are the arpeggios one octave or two? What fingerings are being used? What keys are involved? Things like key spacing, order of black and white keys, and fingering all play roles. Please consider re-asking with specific arpeggios and how you're playing them. Then you can get a precise answer.

Comment: In addition to the above: what inversion of the chords is being arpeggiated?

Comment: I'm only speaking of *academic* arpeggio (those used in all tones used by professional pianist when they train, in the same spirit as they train with scales in all tones), with the *academic fingering*.

Comment: There is not just a single academic fingering. For root-position, two-octave arpeggios, some systems always use 1-2-3-1-2-3-5; other systems start on different fingers for arpeggios beginning on black keys. For other inversions there are even more variations. Professional pianists practice all of these.

Comment: Do you mean that the professionalist pianist practice, for a *given fixed arpeggio tone*, all variantes of fingering ? For what purpose ? I mean : if they prefer one fingering : why would they use the others in their life ?

Comment: I'm saying there are different options for fingering: some pianists use one, some another. There's no single fixed standard. For a given pitch, pianists practice arpeggios for major, minor, diminished, augmented, and all types of seventh chords. Often a pianist will practice a variety of fingerings, because they might be needed for a particular musical context.

Comment: I think showing an example of a difficult arpeggio along with an example of an easier arpeggio in the question would improve it greatly.

Comment: @Todd Wilcox : ok : I will add soon an example of extremely hard and one example easy, in the question

Comment: I added a concrete example so that people don't feel that my question is stupid...

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian The examples are immensely helpful. I've retracted my close vote and encourage others to do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Were there only white keys on a piano, you wouldn't be asking this question.

Were all our digits the same size and length, you wouldn't be asking this question.

Those are the reasons mainly why some arpeggios - and scales for that matter - are more difficult than others.

It would be impossible to have an 88 note keyboard with only white notes - it would be far too wide. So the black keys are squashed in between the white keys, making the keyboard at least practicable.

Arpeggios use different mixes of black and white keys, with several different patterns used. Where possible, short thumbs are used on white rather than black keys, for obvious reasons. But sometimes even that's not possible, so with the difference in location between black and white, it stands to reason some arps will be easier, some not. And having only five digits is a disadvantage too. If humans had more, it'd be easier to move up and down the keyboard. However, we have what we have. So we need to move hands left and right as we play down and up. That thumb then becomes pivotal, literally, in moving laterally. And it isn't always in the most helpful position.

Comment: "It would be impossible to have an 88 note keyboard with only white notes" what about a piano without black keys? ;-) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tB8ITQGp-is

Comment: @musicamante - interesting, but surely not 88 note?

Comment: @Tim yes, it only has the common 52 white keys. And I wouldn't really call it *that* interesting, more an expensive oddity ;-)

Comment: @musicamante - really it should be cheaper. They're saving on all those black bits.

Comment: @Tim theoretically yes, but that depends on how "well" it's built: assuming they're just using a standard piano, removed the mechanical parts and their strings (thus changing its sound also), the only difference would be to create the keys as "plain" rectangles, possibly by only using molds of the high C. But, are they still using the hollow base of other keys? If they only used "white strings", how does it sound? How do string and board react to less tension? Did they change board and materials in order to reflect that? Possibly a lot of expansive thinking and engeneering, done pointlessly...

Comment: @musicamante - there was a point, but not too pointed. Rather like the left-handed piano someone commissioned. Bit of fun though.

Comment: Playing only white keys is _harder_ than a mix of black and white keys.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - matter of opinion. I'm quite happy with white. Ironically, most beginner lessons concentrate purely on them!

Comment: @Tim. Look at LawrencePayne's answer and the point about B major. That was the same attitude as Chopin https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_major. It really isn't opinion, it's about the physical shape of the hand. All white keys is difficult.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>*Answered before we had specific examples in the OP*</sup>
Harder to reach, harder to get an even touch.

Compare C-E-G-C to C♯-F-G♯-C♯

The first is easy to reach - and probably the one you first ever played. You can get your fingers nicely towards the front of each key; lots of room to play with, no issues with squeezing, twisting or being hard to reach.

C♯ on the other hand, because your thumb starts so far back your middle finger might be almost to the back of the key in order to get your little finger on the top C♯, making the whole thing a harder shape & with less leverage.

Additionally, if you extend each of those to two octaves… at what point do you slide your thumb underneath, & to where?

Comment: See my answer above.  Yes, if you put the thumb on a black key it can be very clumsy.   That's why we generally don't.

Answer (score 3):

We need to define 'hard'.   You might consider that C♯ major arpeggio is physically easier than C major.  The fingers are already raised to hit the black notes, the thumb is in natural position for the one white note.

The first scale I teach is right hand B major.  It's impossible to play with a wrong fingering.  SO many ways to mess up the fingering of C major!  And it destroys from the outset any idea that black notes are somehow 'hard'.

You're aware that standard fingering patterns DON'T put the thumb on a black note?

Comment: Thank you. I have added a concrete example : just try my example and you will see how dificult is the first example, as compared to the second one. People in the reply thought that I was speaking about any arpeggio : I was only asking about "academic" arpeggio : those in books of scales/arpeggios.

Comment: I dunno - I keep slipping up and changing my B Major scale fingering if I'm not careful.

Comment: Really?  Right hand?  What are the options?

Comment: This makes a great point about black keys that seems to missed entirely in @Tim's accepted answer.

Comment: @LaurencePayne - Pretty sure I've used RH ring finger on E, LH ring finger on C#, pinky finger on a black note, the random slips go on...(and for repertoire as well as scales and arpeggios)

Comment: @Dekkadeci Wait did you slip and cross your 3 or 4 over your 5? Cause that's the only possibility I could think of which "messes up" the fingering of a r.h. B major scale. And if that's the case, it's really impressive.

Comment: @Divide1918 - RH ring finger on E is a momentary slip of the mind as I use my middle finger just before on D#, LH ring finger on C# is me using the wrong finger to cross over the thumb at this point, pinky finger on black note can be over-extension when crossing over or a slip of mind I really do not catch in time.

Comment: I think I need some context to fully grasp what you meant. Would be nice if you could give an example of which piece you accidentally used a non-standard fingering on the B major scale

Comment: @Dekkadeci  Oh sure.  And I can't really stop you leaning over and playing notes with your nose either!  But at least if you get into a fingering train crash with B major you KNOW it!   There are so many possible fingerings of C major, however, that it's easy to 'practice' a different one each time, preventing your fingers getting trained into any real fluency.

Comment: @Divide1918 - I don't recall any repertoire pieces with B major scale runs (although Schubert's Impromptu in F Minor, D.935, No. 4 has several scale runs), but I remember that scale practice for piano was always kinda heck (and I had a high chance of slipping up and playing wrong notes in scale practice to boot).

Answer (score 2):

The human hand naturally places the thumb on a white key, the 2nd and 3rd fingers on black keys, and the rest on either.  An Arpeggio designed in the reverse of that pattern would be the most difficult.

Answer (score 1):

In the cases of the two arpeggios given, there are very clear differences that make the A major more difficult.

In the A major case, it's an important factor that it is in first inversion. Because of this, if choosing the right-hand fingering that begins with 1 on C#, it forces finger 4 to be placed well between two black keys. This in turn leads to finger 4 getting "stuck" when moving to get finger 1 onto the next C#. In arpeggios one wants to move laterally, but in this case, moving 4 on a white key (i.e., a long finger in a vertically lower position) to 1 on a black key (i.e., crossing a short finger to a vertically higher position) a fairly significant vertical movement is required (at minimum of finger 4 -- a difficult proposition by itself -- if not the whole hand).

For A major, the 2-1-4 right-hand fingering is far superior. I also prefer 4-2-1 for the left hand, which isn't suggested in the given example.

In the F# major case, all notes are at the same vertical height, so the lateral movements are much easier.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you're playing legato, so in A major with the 4 finger on A and the thumb going to C#, you're passing your thumb under and up behind your 4 finger-- quite a challenge.

If you are using pedal, and you can move the 4 finger out of the way so the thumb can pass straight from C# to the next C#, it shouldn't be much harder than the F# chord.  Normally, you'd rather put the thumb on E or A, but sometimes the awkward fingering makes it easier to bring the right note out (i.e. if you really need to bring out the C# as a melodic note).